# I cant move apps like twitter over to SD card?

Tags: sd-card, twitter

Why cant I move twitter over to my SD card? I have a 16gb SD and all installed apps are there,exept for some, like twitter. Is it possible to move those apps over to SD card?

Comment: Any app with a widget cannot be moved to SD (as the widget stops working) also if Twitter is pre-installed it will be a `System app` and as such cannot be moved to SD. You'd have to [tag:root] if you wanted to do this.

Comment: @RossC Your comment seems like a perfectly good answer. Not sure how more complete can one get.

Comment: @Chahk I've added an answer, thanks! Thought there was more to it, but seems to be that.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 possible situations here, or both:

1. System apps cannot be moved to SD due to being 'protected' system apps.
2. Apps that have widgets cannot be moved to SD as it breaks the widget and many devs will take out the option to move to SD.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the 'Twitter' app or is it a system application? In other words, did it come preloaded with the phone? One thing to keep in mind when moving apps to SD card:

> Apps that Shouldn’t be Moved to the SD Card:

- Widgets – no matter how menial in usefulness or design.
- System tools – many might not operate as intended without being on the phone’s storage.
- Important apps – you don’t want to risk an important app becoming inaccessible when you need it.

If the app is not a system app. You should be able to move to SD card. Try stopping the app so that it is not in use when you are attempting to move to SD card. Sometimes the 'Move to SD card' button is grayed out until you 'Force stop' the app.